# What can I do to improve speeds for my website which mainly uses OpenStreetMap

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

Sup.

I built a website (https://pompmeister.nl) which is essentially a big map with gas stations. I'm trying to find ways that I can improve its score on Google's PageSpeed Insights. As far as I'm concerned I've done pretty much everything–from compressing to enabling HTTP2.

Is there anything else I can do, or am I "crippled" by the fact that I'm using a map?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds and looks today like you've worked on server settings, but not addressed the JavaScript that is causing the poor PageSpeed score. If suggestions on where to start would be helpful, let me know.

Comment: That would be helpful, yes.